# List of records for youngest WFMs (woman FIDE masters) since 1950 (or whenever)?

Tags: history, statistics, records, titles, women

On Wiki, we have the [List of youngest grandmasters since 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_prodigy#List_of_youngest_grandmasters). What about WFMs (woman FIDE masters) instead of GMs?

**Note 1**: I really mean to ask about WFMs (females who obtain the female exclusive title WFM) and not [female FMs (females who obtain the open title FM)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/list-of-records-for-youngest-female-fide-masters-since-1950-or-whenever-the-fid).

**Note 2**: WCM was answered here: [List of records for youngest WCMs (woman candidate masters) since 1950?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/list-of-records-for-youngest-wcms-woman-candidate-masters-since-1950)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching my database constructed from data available on the [FIDE Ratings Download][2] page gives the following results. Note that FIDE gives only the birth year for players due to data privacy laws so age was calculated as 'Year of title' - 'Year of birth' so Salimova, Nurgyul may have actually been only 7 years old when she won the title.

**Year Name Age Fed**
1981    Brustman, Agnieszka 19  POL
1984    Olarasu, Iuliana    17  ROU
1985    Maric, Alisa    15  YUG
1988    Polgar, Judit   12  HUN
1990    Stefanova, Antoaneta    11  BUL
2004    Hou, Yifan  10  CHN
2007    Salcedo, Jackeline  9   COL
2011    [Salimova, Nurgyul](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2915138)  8   BUL

Comment: thanks! wait judit polgar was WFM? i thought judit (almost?) never did any of the WCM, WFM, WIM, WGM titles and never played women's championships and stuff. wait so what else, judit polgar was WIM and WGM too?

Comment: @BCLC Could be an error in the Olimpbase files for July 1988 - http://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/Elo198807e.html and for Judit http://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Polgar,%20Judit.html. I've said before that their data is dirty.

Comment: 'Could be an error ' --> maybe not. apparently WFM (and even WGM) is based only on ratings --> is this true? seems to be false based on this: https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B01Regulations2017